# Paging3 without RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging, android-paging-3

I know that the Paging3 library was designed to work together with RecyclerView, however I have a use case where the paged results are also presented on a map. If you look inside the PagingDataAdapter class, you will notice that it is backed by AsyncPagingDiffer. So for now, I'm trying to make it work using the AsyncPagingDiffer class, which in turn receives a ListUpdateCallback, so that UI is notified when data updates occur. Thus, as soon as ListUpdateCallback dispatches any update, I should be able to retrieve the data just by calling AsyncPagingDiffer.snapshot().

This snippet illustrates well what I'm trying to do:

```kotlin
class MapAdapter : ListUpdateCallback {

    private val differ = AsyncPagingDataDiffer(MapDiff(), this)

    suspend fun submitData(pagingData: PagingData<Foo>) {
        differ.submitData(pagingData)
    }

    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
        val data = differ.snapshot()
        // Update UI
    }

    // Other callbacks...
}
```

but the snapshot is always empty or out of date when trying to recover it this way. In other words, the snapshot is actually available only after the callback has already been notified, which to me is unwanted behavior.

I can confirm that this approach works with Paging 2 (or whatever it is called), but I wish there was some way to use it with Paging 3 as well, as I am reluctant to downgrade other features that are underway with Paging 3.